# How to resolve Multiple assemblies being imported on a newly imported Nuget package for Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, nuget

*Disclaimer, I am creating the Nuget in question.*

I am currently in the process of creating a Nuget package for Xamarin Forms, which has been going great. [Here is the repo](https://github.com/LuckyDucko/AwaitablePopups). I have gotten it fully working no issues.

I have also been testing it by including it as a project reference in another, closed source, repo. And this has also been working perfectly fine.

However, I decided to switch from using the project reference to using the actual Nuget, since I was no longer tinkering with the code on the fly to make it work correctly, and I have hit a wall.

The moment I include the package, I am given upward of 5000 errors, which are either

> `(/Users/UserHere/Projects/PopupsError/PopupsError.Android/CSC: Error CS1703: Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: /Users/UserHere/.nuget/packages/awaitablepopups/0.2.5/lib/netstandard2.0/System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll' and /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild-frameworks/MonoAndroid/v1.0/Facades/System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll. Remove one of the duplicate references. (CS1703) (PopupsError.Android))`

or

> `(/Users/UserHere/Projects/PopupsError/PopupsError.Android/Resources/Resource.designer.cs(36,36): Error CS0731: The type forwarder for type 'System.Attribute' in assembly 'netstandard' causes a cycle (CS0731) (PopupsError.Android))`

And a multitude of others, I have a completely fresh repo with just the Nuget added [here](https://github.com/LuckyDucko/AwaitablePopupsError)

The bit that is most confusing to me, is that the same exact project works as a project reference, but if I make it a Nuget and add it in, then it throws the error seen above.

I am under the impression, that its some small option I could add, but after some research, I am unable to figure out what small option I should tick. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question. How are you generating the nuget, Just using visual studio right click and pack or using command line with explicit file to include the assemblies?

Comment: I have tried both using just pack in Visual studio for Mac, and using
``` dotnet pack --configuration Release```

Comment: you should share your nuspec file in here. Also you can check the included assemblies in from nupkg file with VS Code extension eridem.vscode-nupkg

Comment: Nuspec for 0.2.5
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETStandard2.0" />
    </dependencies>



However, I rebuilt using .NetStandard 2.1 and got this

    <tags>Xamarin-forms async popups MVVM</tags>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETStandard2.1">
        <dependency id="AsyncAwaitBestPractices" version="4.1.0" />
        <dependency id="Rg.Plugins.Popup" version="1.2.0.223" />
        <dependency id="AsyncAwaitBestPractices.MVVM" version="4.1.0" />
        <dependency id="Xamarin.Forms" version="4.5.0.396" />
      </group>
    </dependencies>

Comment: Ok..I will try it on my Windows machine, master branch or dev?

Comment: Master branch, I should probably set up a proper dev one.

Comment: Ok.I was able to generate nupkg with small change and add the nuget into new project and built with no issues. (Windows) do you want me to submit PR ?

Comment: That would be super Prateek :)

Comment: Solution is to remove NuGet.Build.Packaging nuget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is sometimes headache.

### For local projects migrating from packages.config to PackageReference

You have to go and delete duplicate nuget from physical disk.

Delete this folder /Users/UserHere/.nuget/packages/awaitablepopups/0.2.5/lib/netstandard2.0

Since you mentioned you moved from **packages.config** to `PackageReference` within *csproj* file, you have to be also careful that csproj still doesnt have old style imports , you can fix this by comparing your *csproj* file with newly created project *csproj* file as reference.

Delete and remove `"package.config"` and 'app.config` reference from csproj file as well.

## Update

### For NuGet

- Check .nuspec file and remove reduntant imports
- Clean the project , delete bin obj folders manually as well.
- Remove `NuGet.Build.Packaging` , its not required. Its adding all of those reduntant assemblies.

Comment: While this does work initially, it doesn't seem to solve the root error, as if I completely remove the package and redownload from Nuget.org. it will still contain that folder. How do I remove that folder from ever existing in my Nuget in the first place.
(I rename to zip, then extract and in lib, I can see netstandard2.0)

[Nuget Download](https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/AwaitablePopups/0.2.5)

Comment: Add on, Visual Studio for Mac seems to add Nuget.Build.Packaging in its Nuget template. Otherwise, removing this fixed it all up

Comment: none of these work unfortunately if project is too old. Simply create a new project and copy the classes and reinstall the nugets. only working solution